# PHP: Fill combobox after choosing one option from another combobox using MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I have one combobox where I choose one option filled it up with the table 'distrito' where the columns it's 'ID' and 'nome'.

So far, so good. The problem is when I want to fill it up the other combobox depending on the option select in the first combobox. The table 'localidade' that fills this combobox uses the columns 'id', 'nome' and 'id_distrito'.

This is the code to fill the first combobox called 'distrito':

```
<?php

// Connects to your Database 
 include "config.php";

 $QUERY_LISTAR_DISTRITO = "SELECT id, nome FROM distrito";

 $DISTRITO = mysql_query($QUERY_LISTAR_DISTRITO) or die(mysql_error());
 $nr_distrito = mysql_num_rows($DISTRITO);

 while ($nr_distrito > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($DISTRITO);

    echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
    $nr_distrito--;
 }
?>
```

This is the code to fill the second combobox called 'localidade':

```
    <?php   
// Connects to your Database 
 include "config.php";

 $id_distrito = $_GET['distrito'];

 $QUERY_LISTAR_LOCALIDADE = "SELECT * FROM localidade WHERE localidade.id_distrito = $id_distrito";

 $LOCALIDADE = mysql_query($QUERY_LISTAR_LOCALIDADE) or die(mysql_error());
 $nr_localidade = mysql_num_rows($LOCALIDADE);

 while ($nr_localidade > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($LOCALIDADE);

    echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
    $nr_localidade--;
 }
 ?>
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="registarGestorBD.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Distrito: <select name="distrito" id="distrito">
                <?php include 'listarDistritos.php'; ?>
            </select> <br> <br>
Localidade: <select name="localidade" id="localidade">
                <?php include 'listarLocalidades.php'; ?>
            </select> <br> <br>
<input  type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Guardar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can't do like this on it's own, you have to use javascript or jQuery.(hint: ajax)

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem. Change your HTML file to this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <title>Test</title>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
   <form action="registarGestorBD.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       Distrito: <select name="distrito" id="distrito">
            <?php include 'listarDistritos.php'; ?>
        </select> <br> <br>
       Localidade: <select name="localidade" id="localidade">

        </select> <br> <br>
       <input  type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Guardar">
   </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).on('change','#distrito',function(){
             var val = $(this).val();
             $.ajax({
                   url: 'listarLocalidades.php',
                   data: {distrito:val},
                   type: 'GET',
                   dataType: 'html',
                   success: function(result){
                        $('#localidade').html();  
                        $('#localidade').html(result); 
                   }
              });
       });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is basically an ajax call which will fire on the selection of first combo box. The ajax call will sends the value of the first combo box and will query the other table based on id.

this might help you

[Combobox items based on selected item in another combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370478/combobox-items-based-on-selected-item-in-another-combobox)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be looking at ajax.  Consider this example (modified from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))):

```
    function sendToServer(){

      // Initialize the Ajax request
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('post', 'send-ajax-data.php');

      // Track the state changes of the request
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
          // Ready state 4 means the request is done
          if(xhr.readyState === 4){
              // 200 is a successful return
              if(xhr.status === 200){
                  var options = xhr.responseText.split(",");
                  populateComboBox(options)

              }
          }
      }

      // Send the request to send-ajax-data.php
      xhr.send(distrito_id);
        }

    function populateComboBox(options){
        var combo = document.getElementById("localidade");
        $(options).each(function(i){
            var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContext = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            combo.appendChild(el);

        })
    }
```

Then of course in your php, get the post variable distrito_id, do your query and return the results in a comma separated list!